# how to configure multi site with drupal on main server

Tags: drupal

how to configure multi site with drupal on main server

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific problem it would be more helpful to describe it, but here is a general "How To" link that might help you out:  http://drupal.org/node/43816

Comment: But this working on intranet. How to configure this on mail hosting 
server 
eg://www.abc.com

Answer (score 0):

You can do it one of two ways:

- Drupal Multisite install methods
  http://drupal.org/node/43816
- Domain
  Access module
  http://drupal.org/project/domain

Depends on your purpose and what you are trying to achieve. If you're new, Domain Access may be a good first step (one Drupal installation manages multiple sites).